# jQuery Get Specific ID From Multiple Textbox

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I have multiple textbox from loop.

Example:

```
1. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0001"/>
2. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0006"/>
3. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0004"/>
4. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0002"/>
5. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0008"/>
```

The textbox has been sorted and now I want to get example ID textbox 3, or sometimes I want to get ID textbox 5.

How can I do that using jQuery? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('input.inputText:eq(index)')` to get element.

```js
console.log($('input.inputText:eq(2)').attr('id')); // get inputText #3
console.log($('input.inputText:eq(4)').attr('id')); // get inputText #5
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0001"/><br>
2. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0006"/><br>
3. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0004"/><br>
4. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0002"/><br>
5. <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0008"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using better `id` properties to begin with, but you can use jQuery's `.children()` function if there is a parent container such as a `div`.

```js
$(function() {
  var inputs = $('#inputs').children('input');
  
  // Get a random input
  console.log(inputs[Math.random() * inputs.length << 0])
  
  // Get a specific input
  console.log(inputs[3]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0001"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0006"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0004"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0002"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0008"/>
  <span>random element</span>
</div>
```

You can also use a jQuery selector that matches all inputs with `id` properties containing "CM".

```js
$(function() {
  var inputs = $('input[id*="CM"]');
  console.log(inputs);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0001"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0006"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0004"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0002"/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" id="CM0008"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but in its simplest form, to get a specific input field by ID, based on your example, you would use the following:

```
$('#CM0001').val();
```

Or if you wanted a function that can accept the ID as a variable and allow you to choose any of your input fields (by ID), you could use something like this:

```
function getInputVal(fieldID){
    var chosenID = '#'+fieldID;
    return $(chosenID).val();
}
```

and use it like so: 
    getInputVal('CM0006');